# i need help for use ip camera in python and open cv

Tags: python, opencv

my original code for cam is

```
import cv2.cv as cv
import time

cv.NamedWindow("camera", 1)

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)

while True:
    img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.ShowImage("camera", img)
    if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
        break
cv.DestroyAllWindows()
```

what I change,,not the  ip for camera is 20.0.0.14

Comment: Which camera is using ?

Answer (score 1):

Find out your camera model from the list https://www.ispyconnect.com/sources.aspx . And change the code like this. I assumed that using [HoneyWell](https://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=Honeywell) Camera.

```
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture("http://IPADDRESS/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi")

while True:
    img,ret = capture.read()
    cv2.imshow("camera", img)
    if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: the code run without any error but no results whats is the problem

Comment: Can you paste the link here that you given ?

Comment: no error given and not do any think if i change the ip address make error that make sure the ip correct but camera window not open